# Gerrit: Start FAILED, no logs

Tags: gerrit

Fedora 27 with openjdk 1.8.0 and Gerrit 2.14.7.

This is what I get:

```
gerrit_testsite/bin/gerrit.sh start
Starting Gerrit Code Review: FAILED
```

The logs are empty. There is a `gerrit.pid` file; the corresponding process is running:

```
GerritCodeReview -jar /home/gerrit2/gerrit_testsite/bin/gerrit.war daemon -d /home/gerrit2/gerrit_testsite --run-id=1521606266.3474
```

But nothing listens at the configured port 8080.

When I add the -x option, I can see the gerrit.sh script is timing out waiting for a `gerrit.run` file to appear - which doesn't happen.

I tried increasing the timeout to 600 seconds.

I tried `gerrit.sh run`. This does create an error log with two warnings:

```
[main] WARN  com.google.gerrit.sshd.SshDaemon : Cannot format SSHD host key [EdDSA]: invalid key type
[main] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.config.GitwebCgiConfig : gitweb not installed (no /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi found)
```

Again, nothing listens on 8080.

I believe that I was able to run Gerrit for the very first time. I had to change the canonicalWebUrl parameter, restarted Gerrit and have had the problem ever since. I removed my gerrit_testsite directory and reinitialized it, but starting it up keeps failing.

What is the SSHD key warning about? Do I need gitweb? Where else to look?

**EDIT**: I restarted from a fresh Fedora installation. Then:

```
$ java -jar gerrit.war init -d ~/review-site
....
Initialized /home/gerrit2/review-site
Executing /home/gerrit2/review-site/bin/gerrit.sh start
Starting Gerrit Code Review: FAILED
error: cannot start Gerrit: exit status 1
Waiting for server on 192.168.1.201:8080 ... OK
Opening http://192.168.1.201:8080/#/admin/projects/ ...FAILED
Open Gerrit with a JavaScript capable browser:
  http://192.168.1.201:8080/#/admin/projects/
```

In spite of the FAILED message, I do find a `gerrit.run` file in the logs directory. `error_log` contains the same two warnings as earlier. The GerritCodeReview process listens on port 8080, and I have access via web browser. For now, life is good, but I wonder what happens when I have to restart Gerrit.

**EDIT2**: Yes, as I feared, after `gerrit.sh restart`, not only do I get FAILED, but nothing listens on the web port 8080 nor on the SSH port 29418.

**EDIT3**: In summary, to me it looks like I can successfully start Gerrit on an entirely new OS, but as soon as I restart it, something makes it either wait for an event that never happens, or crash before writing to the log.

Comment: I have the same problem with 2.15.1 on Debian 8. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Not yet. Admittedly my Gerrit installation project is currently on hold. I will probably revive it in the next weeks, so watch this space.

Comment: On my installation it seems that if I wait long enough, eventually it starts and functions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and the hint to the fix is right here, in your logs:

```
[main] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.config.GitwebCgiConfig : gitweb not installed (no /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi found)
```

You don't have gitweb installed and you have it configured in your system. Either remove the gitweb configuration from gerrit.config:

```
[gitweb]
    type = gitweb
    cgi = /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi
```

Or make sure it is properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be *lack of entropy*. Gerrit reads from /dev/random, and on a headless server the entropy might be exhausted before Gerrit has had time to start up.

A fix could be to install the `haveged` package.
Since you're on Fedora, the required commands would be:

```
yum install haveged
chkconfig haveged on
service haveged start
```

After doing this, Gerrit should start relatively quickly.

Note: I've found this solution [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged).